# Shell script to remove files with no extension

Tags: file, shell

I need a shell script to remove files without an extension (like `.txt` or any other extension). For example,  I found a file named as `imeino1` (without `.txt` or any other thing) and I want to delete them via shell script, so if any developer know about this part, please explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No finds, no pipes, just plain old shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"; do
  case $file in
  (*.*) ;; # do nothing
  (*) rm -- "$file";;
  esac
done
```

Run with a list of files as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a UNIX(-like) shell, you can use the `rm` command:

```
rm imeino1
```

Answer (score 0):

`for file in $(find . -type f | grep -v '\....$') ; do rm $file 2>/dev/null; done`

Removes all files not ending in `.???` in the current directory.

Comment: In shell, it would be more normal to write "not ending with `.???`". Sadly, though, the grep regex you use simply looks for any four characters at the end of the line, so it only allows through file names that are 3 characters or less in length.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo, it has to be \.... obviously :)

Apparently it wasn't a typo, ironically I had to escape the escape char, haha. I use bash btw.

Comment: YW.  You might want to look up the `xargs` command, and also why it isn't a particularly good idea to process the output of `find` (or `ls`) in `$(…)` captures.  Find out what happens when a file name contains a space — or, worse, a newline.  Could you do it all in one with `find . -type f '!' -name '*.[!.][!.][!.]' -exec rm {} +`? (Casual experimentation suggests the answer is 'yes, you could'.)  However, that is for strictly 3-character extensions.  You could simplify the `-name` to `'!' -name '*.*'` to list files with no dot in the name at all.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thank you for the pointers, I am still a beginning shell user and eager to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rvf `ls -lrth|grep -v ".txt"`
```

`ls -lrth|grep -v ".txt"` should be inside back-quotes `` `…` ``(or, better, inside `$(…)`).

If other filenames are not containing "." then instead of giving `.txt` for `grep -v`, you can give

`` rm  -rvf `ls -lrth|grep -v "."` ``

This will remove all the directories and files in the path without extension.

`` rm -vf `ls -lrth|grep -v "."` `` won't remove directories, but will remove all the files without extension (if the filename does not contain the character ".").

Answer (score 0):

To remove all files in or below the current directory that contain no dot in the name, regardless of whether the names contain blanks or newlines or any other awkward characters, you can use a POSIX 2008-compliant version of `find` (such as found with GNU `find`, or BSD `find`):

```
find . -type f '!' -name '*.*' -exec rm {} +
```

This looks for files (not directories, block devices, …) with a name that does not match `*.*` (so does not contain a `.`) and executes the `rm` command on conveniently large groups of such file names.